# (UNITY) Plane not rotating to normal vector of three points?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to get a stretched out cube (which we can call a plane for the sake of discussion) to orient itself to the normal vector of a plane described by three points. I wrote a script to find the normal of three points, and then used transform.LookAt to have the planes align. However, I am finding that this script is not working at all how it is intended to and despite my best efforts I can not figure out why.

drastic movements of the individual points hardly effect the planes rotation.

the rotation of the object when using the existing points in the script should be 0,0,0 in the inspector. However, it is always off by a few degrees and as i said does not align itself when I move the points around.

[This is the script. I can also post photos showing the behavior or share a small unity package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fakpW.png)

Comment: [**Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Please rather copy & paste the raw text into your question and format it as `code` using the `{ }` button (or simply by indentating everything by 4 spaces) ;)

Answer (score 1):

First of all [`Transform.LookAt`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) takes a **position** as parameter, not a **direction**!

And then it

> Rotates the transform so the **forward vector** points at `worldPosition`.

Doesn't sound like what you are trying to achieve.

---

If you want your object to look with its **forward** vector in the given normal direction (assuming you are calculating the normal correctly) then you could rather use [`Quaternion.LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html)

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(doNormal(cpit, cmit, ctht);
```

alternatively to this you can also simply assign the according vector directly like e.g.

```
transform.forward = doNormal(cpit, cmit, ctht);
```

or

```
transform.up = doNormal(cpit, cmit, ctht);
```

depending on your needs